# What speaks against using structs for passive data structures?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

### Context

I recently read about the object-oriented technique of making a distinction between **objects** and **passive data structures**, best summarized in Clean Code:

> "Objects hide their data [...] and expose functions [...]. Data
>   structures expose their data and have no meaningful functions."

I am considering using C# `structs` for **passive data structures**.
To clarify this: IF part of my code needs to function as a **passive data structure**, THEN I want to use a `struct` for that.

### Advantages

It would provide a language-given distinction between **objects** and **passive data structures**.

Also, if an object has a private field of a `class`, but exposes that in a function, it can be changed somewhere else. That means the **object** data is changed from the outside, which is not good. I know you should e.g. expose an internal `List` as `ReadOnlyList`, but that is *good practice*, which even good programmers don't always follow. Using `structs` instead would *automatically enforce* this.

### What I found out so far

I know the question "[When to use `struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct)" is already answered several times. The answers always boil down to the advice from the official docs:

> AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

I think the first 2 points are for improving performance on the stack. However, as far as I understand `structs` are better on the stack, but not worse on the heap.

Point 3 I can still adhere to. Might make the code cleaner, might make it more awkward, but I don't know yet.

Point 4 is also about performance improvements, but I also actually don't need a lot of performance. Even if, at this point that would be early, early optimization - I'm not working with big data here.

With a name like that, I want to think `structs` are *exactly* the thing to use for object oriented **passive data structures**. The documentation from the official docs makes me doubt that though, especially the size limitation. Even 2 strings for an address with 2 rows would already be too much.

### The question

Are there other arguments against using structs for these passive data structures? Or did I understand something wrong?

### Example

```
public struct EmployeeId // data structure (exposed data, no functions)
{
    public string Value;
}

public struct Address // data structure
{
    public string Line1;
    public string Line2;
}

public struct Performance // data structure
{
    public int Successes;
    public int Failures;
}

public struct Employee : IEquatable<Employee>
// data structure
{
    public EmployeeId Id:
    public Address Address;
    public Performance Performance;

    public bool Equals(Employee employee)
    {
        return Id == employee.Id;
    }
}

public class OfficialEmployeeRegistry // object (hidden data, exposed functions)
{
    private Dictionary<EmployeeId, Employee> _employees;

    public void Add(Employee employee)
    {
        _employees.Add(employee.Id, employee);
    }

    public List<Employee> GetPositivePerformers() {...}
}

public class SantaClause // object
{
    private EmployeeRegistry _employeeRegistry;
    private PresentSender _presentSender;

    public void SendChristmasPresents()
    {
        List<Employee> goodEmployees = employeeRegistry.GetPositivePerformers();
        foreach(Employee employee in goodEmployees)
        {
            _presentSender.SendPresent(employee.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

All `structs` in this code are examples of what I want to do. For example, we can get the performance of an employee from the `OfficialEmployeeRegistry` now. We can send that data to a printer class, but if that class changes it in the process, the entries in the `OfficialEmployeeRegistry` are protected. OfficialEmployeeRegistry data will only be manipulated by itself. Oh, and the structs are supposed to be immutable of course, but I feel adding a constructor to each would bloat this post to much.

### Reaction to commments

*Do you require data serialization?*
No.

*Will this need to be passed into and from functions/methods?*
Yes.

*Will it be iterated and modified on a fairly significant basis?*
No. I guess this is about performance; but performance is definitely not an issue

Comment: Downvoters care to explain? I'd like to think the question shows research effort and is clear and useful.

Comment: Could you give an example of a class that you are thinking of turning into a class?

Comment: Just a few thoughts off the top of my head: Do you require data serialization? Will this need to be passed into and from functions/methods? Will it be iterated and modified on a fairly significant basis? Also: immutability on a monolithic basis means that you need to "batten down the hatches" on multiple levels of concerns (not a bad thing, just a... thing).

Comment: NOTE: I will warn you that working with structs in lists will not behave the way you expect them to.  Mixing and matching value types with object types will lead to a number of unexpected maintenance headaches.  Try it for a while, then ask a colleague to implement a change to your code.  The feedback will be _very_ informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What speaks against using structs for passive data structures?

**Technically, nothing.**

(if you can live with the some restrictions mentioned by Erik Eidt, like no inheritance).

I am pretty sure if you try to use C# structs for all of your data objects, you can still write correct programs following this convention. The 16 byte size limitation is only a recommendation for performance, and can be safely ignored.

However, the real question you should ask yourself is, does this convention produce better maintainable, evolvable, readable programs, compared to programs which follow the more usual C# convention to use classes in most cases, even for most kind of DTOs or "passive data structures", and structs only for exceptional cases.

And that is IMHO questionable. I usually prefer to use **classes first and foremost** in my programs (even for pure data objects, when I only need a list of public member functions), and use `struct` only for such optimizations like mentioned by @Ivan. The reason is I made the experience that often when I start with a small data structure where a simple struct would be suffient, over time new requirements to this structures cause some evolvement where then a full class starts to make more sense. And if I have used that `struct` in various places of the program, changing it into a class afterwards can introduce a lot of subtile errors because of the switch from value semantics to reference semantics.

Moreover, if a type is defined as a `struct` or as a `class` is not immediately detectable when reading code using that type. However, there are subtile semantic differences between the two (see the comment from @BerinLoritsch below the question). Using `struct` only for exceptional optimization cases makes errors in my code caused by those differences less likely.

So my recommendation here is, use `struct`s exclusively for passive data structures when you know for sure this particular data structure will never ever evolve to a class, and only if you have a useful optimization scenario. And if in doubt, better use a class.

Comment: Your analysis of the situation is spot on. I changed "data structure" to "passive data structure". I don't really like DTO as name for these, as it might be used internally by an object without any *transfer* ever happening. Now, changing later on would indeed be painful, but I can't imagine how that would happen in the first place. How does data turn into something you want to do? I'd suspect you want another object working on that data instead.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz: If it doesn't contain any methods, then such a class is a data transfer object by definition, since the only thing it is capable of is transferring a bundle of data from one place to another.

Comment: @Robert Harvey After my blunder with the name confusion, I'm going to rely on Wikipedia for my term definitions from now. What they have to say about this matter is "A value object is not a DTO. The two terms have been conflated by Java developers in the past." Are you by any chance a Java developer from the past? ;) And then the answerer is "Doc Brown" - It's getting very time travely here...

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer. The reason is that what I'm suggesting hasn't been tried yet, as far as the answers go. We don't know if this will work or fail yet and this answer doesn't try to guess that. Instead, it mentions actual practical difficulties in a situation encountered in current everyday programming, which would be applicable to my suggested way of doing things.

Answer (score 13):

You're confusing the `struct` keyword with the term "data structure."  They are two very different things.  Greatly simplifying, a `struct` in C# is basically a `class` with value semantics, whereas a data structure is a *collection* of data with storage and retrieval algorithms that have specific performance characteristics.

> "Objects hide their data [...] and expose functions [...]. Data structures expose their data and have no meaningful functions."

Given that definition, what you're looking for is not a `struct`, but rather a *`class` with data members only (no functions).* `struct`s have *value semantics,* which is probably not what you want to put in a collection unless you really are collecting *values.*

Accordingly, using the `struct` keyword to signal that you're collecting data with no behavior is probably not a good approach.  Competent software developers already know that their data structures are going to contain *classes of objects;* your use of a language keyword that suggests otherwise will be confusing to them.

Use `struct` to *indicate value semantics,* not to indicate "data-only objects."

**See Also**
[Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)
[Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)
[Passive Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I feel like you must have just skimmed my question?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Your first paragraph starts with "You're confusing A and B" My question literally asks about "using A *for* B". I also carefully marked the language features "class" and "struct" as code and the OO concepts "object" and "data structure" in bold. I also completely concur with your take on what those things mean. I even reread my question a couple of times, but I can't find any part where I talk about the language features as if they were OO concepts or vice versa.

Comment: Then the second part of your answer; my question is "Are there arguments against using a [struct instead of class]?" Your answer is "you're looking for a class". That is not an answer to a yes-or-no question and in some way the opposite of what I'm asking for. You probably see how answering a different question makes it seem as if you only picked up a few keywords from the question instead of reading it. However, maybe I'm just really bad at explaining. Maybe look at Erik Eidt's answer, he got it right.

Comment: `Your first paragraph starts with "You're confusing A and B" My question literally asks about "using A for B"` -- Data structures *do not care* what you put into them, but  you'll screw them up by insisting on using value type semantics for everything. `struct` isn't a synonym for "data only."

Comment: At this point, with three upvoted answers that you think are not addressing the question you have, you should strongly consider revising your post, @RaphaelSchmitz. If everybody's misunderstanding you, it's likely that you're not saying what you think you're saying.

Comment: `Your answer is "you're looking for a class". That is not an answer to a yes-or-no question and in some way the opposite of what I'm asking for.` -- Fair enough, but you can see why I might have thought that you were confusing a `struct` with a Data Structure, right?  Your question was "What speaks against using structs for data structures?", to which I responded *"A struct is not a data structure."*

Comment: @Josh Caswell As I said in my previous comment, at that point, one of those three was right. Check Erik Eidt's answer. I did also revise my post though.

Comment: @Robert Harvey "Competent software developers already know that their data structures are going to contain classes of objects" - I thought OO objects would be represented by a class which implements its exposed functions by working on private data structures. I added some example code of what i mean, maybe that clears it up?

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz: More or less, except that your `struct`s should be `class`es, and your public variables should be properties.  I noticed that you're still calling those classes "data structures (exposed data, no methods).  Those are not "data structures," at least not in the way the vast majority of software developers use that term.  Better terms you can use: Data Transfer Object (DTO), Plain Old Csharp Object (POCO), Anemic Data Model.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz: Also worth noting: the code you provided isn't really object-oriented.  Perhaps you come from a C background; the kind of coding style you are using here is very reminiscent of C procedural style, *including the use of `struct`.*

Comment: @Robert Harvey My understanding of a data structure is like described  [here](https://hackernoon.com/objects-vs-data-structures-e380b962c1d2) and in the book "Clean Code". Is that not how it is generally understood? Concerning my snapshot not being really OO... The SNIPPET has 4 data ...things and 2 objects, so yes. A typical app would have way more functionality per data though, and all that functionality would be objects.

Comment: In the C world, we normally just refer to this as a `struct`.  The term "Data Structure" is more commonly associated with things like binary trees, skip lists, hash tables, linked lists and so forth, especially when you move into object-oriented languages like C# and Java.  You can read more about Data Structures in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure).

Comment: "A record (also called tuple or struct) is an aggregate data structure". That is a bit different than I understood it, but does seem to support my idea.

Comment: See also [Passive Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure).  The term "aggregate" has a different meaning in Domain-Driven Design; see https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html

Comment: Yes, passive data structure, that's it. I'll add the word passive in the question.

Comment: Well, you still wouldn't use a `struct`.  You seem to be getting mired in vocabulary, but missing the entire point of your question, which is this: *"Should I use `struct` to indicate a passive data structure?"*  The answer is *"No, because doing so also changes the semantics of your object.  Use `struct` only when you want the semantics that the `struct` keyword provides."*

Comment: You *almost* got me right. I would like the advantages of struct semantics for my passive data structures, that is the premise of the question - but if that is a stupid thing to do, I want to know why it's stupid so I can stop myself.

Comment: Will you ever need passive data structures that don't logically represent a data value, are greater than 16 bytes in size, are mutable, or are free from the performance penalties of boxing?  If any of these things apply, you shouldn't use a `struct`.

Answer (score 6):

The C# struct concept, as you are seeing elsewhere, is a value notion.

Thus, a field of type struct is a value, not a reference.  A field of type struct is an embedded value.

This doesn't map particularly well to [recursive data types](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type), like trees and lists.  These recursive data types need multiple entities that can reference each other.

In order to get multiple objects and references, you need to box the structs, so they become objects. This can be done a number of ways.  One is to use interfaces, but now you're implementing methods (though mostly just getters).  Another is to use `unsafe` pointers.  And yet another is to upcast, which loses valuable (compile time) type information. None of these is attractive compared to the simplicity of classes with public fields.

C# structs also don't play nicely with inheritance and polymorphism (or tagged unions).  We can't use one struct as the base for another. Though we can embed one in another, that is also awkward when we wanted polymorphism, which we might want to use in some recursive data types.

Classes can be made immutable, support polymorphism, and references, so work rather well for data structures, especially recursive data types.

Comment: I haen't thought about that yet, but there's also a couple of things I don't understand. A) "recursive data types need multiple entities that can reference each other" - the items in a list don't know about each other though? Except in a linked list? B) "you need to box the structs [...] This can be done a number of ways" - Doesn't List<MyStruct> work? C) "C# structs also don't play nicely with inheritance and polymorphism" - It will enforce favoring composition over inheritance. I also feel like the data shouldn't really inherit. Polymorphism is still possible with interfaces.

Comment: "the items in a list don't know about each other though?"  It depends on the level of abstraction that you're looking at.  From the client's perspective, using List or some IList implementation, sure the elements added to the list don't know about each other.  From a List implementer's perspective, even though the elements don't know about each other, there are other (internal) objects and references that comprise core of the list data structure that do know about each other.  These provide for core capabilities (e.g. of lists, trees) such as insert, delete, iterate, find, etc..

Comment: But I AM a client. AFAIK the consensus on how to do your own IList etc. implementations is "Don't", as it probably already has been done, better than your homebrew will turn out. I seriously expect to never write an IList implementation my whole life.

Answer (score 2):

It's amazing how just changing the spin of a statement will change its sentiment...

Choose a struct *instead of* a class if:

- It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
- It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
- It is immutable.
- It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Some other points to consider:

- All the fields of a struct should themselves be structs or primitive types.
- If identity doesn't make much sense for the data type, then make it a struct. (I.E. if two equal objects are essentially indistinguishable.)

To be specific and direct:

> Are there other arguments against using structs for these data structures? Or did I understand something wrong?

There is no argument against using struct for data structures that satisfy the conditions above.

Regarding types that don't *quite* satisfy them...

If your type has to be boxed frequently, then the type probably doesn't represent a value.

If your type isn't immutable, then it doesn't behave like a value.

If the instance size is over 16 bytes but otherwise fulfills the requirements of being a struct, then have the type hold a heap object internally so it will be 16 bytes.

If it isn't logically a single value, then it should not be a struct.

Comment: That is the answer to that other question, "When to use struct".

Comment: That's the point. If the data type satisfies the criteria, there is no reason to avoid using a `struct`.

Comment: They don't though. *That's* the point. Of this question. An answer to a when question also can't be an answer to a **yes-or-no question**. Although I have to admit, it's about pretty abstract stuff. You're not the only one with an answer for a different question. I am pretty certain though that it can not be answered by inverting some bool conditions in the docs.

Comment: Hopefully my addition will be more to your liking.

Comment: @DanielT., the 16 byte caveat is mainly for performance since the value is passed by copy.  You could argue that if it isn't done often it could still be a struct.  There is one reason to use a struct that is outside of these parameters, and that's for `IProgress<T>` which is intended to let you use a struct to keep track of where you are and send a snapshot to the handler to update a progress bar or something like that.

Comment: @DanielT the 16 bytes limit was one of my main concerns, so I do like that addition, but what do you consider logically a single value? I added some example code, you would probably consider EmployeeId a single value, but what about Address and Employee?

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz `Address` makes sense as a struct but not `Employee`. After all, you can't really compare them for equality (as required by any value type.) For example, if you had two Employee "objects" that both had the same value for EmployeeID but different values for address or performance, you would not consider them as representing different Employees that happen to have the same ID.

Comment: @DanielT Oh, in that example EmployeeId is meant to be *the* unique identifier for an employee. I adjusted the code to show that. Two Employee data structures with the same EmployeeId but different values for Address should only happen during the process of updating an Employee's Address.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz Yes, I understand. Your change in the example shows exactly why `Employee` isn't a value and thus shouldn't be a struct. I can have two Employee objects that are "equal" yet one of them can have the wrong value while the other doesn't. That can't happen with a value like Int. If two Int's are equal, they are indistinguishable. Two Employees can be distinguishable *despite* being equal. Another way to put it: Classes have identity independent of state while structs don't.

Comment: The `Employee` struct is like data of an employee written on an index card. There can be 50 cards of the same employee with different data in the office. What makes the difference is such a card being in the company's employee register. It's not a specific object which will need to do things like GoToLunchBreak() (the only acceptable goto) or BringBirthdayCake(). Even worse, identity makes it possible for an employee to put a zero behind his successes on a performance review and it would be reflected in the official company database. Am I missing some advantage of identity?

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz If I have two index cards with the same employeeID but different addresses on them, they are not "equal". If your Employee type represents an "index card" then implement == correctly and change its name. I think EmployeeData would be a more accurate.

Comment: You are correct. Two index cards with the same EmployeeId mean they are about the same person, but they are not the same index card. No name change though! "AddressData" would be a more accurate, well, `string` for `Address` and "SantaClauseObject" for `SantaClause`. One of the advantages I mentioned though is that you have a *language given* distinction between objects and data, so you don't need to put that information at the end of the type name. In the way we see "!=" and think "is not" we can see `struct XY` as "XYData" and `class XY` as "XYObject".

Answer (score 0):

The biggest distinction in behavior between a `struct` and a `class` is that a `struct` is passed by value while a `class` is passed by reference.  There are many surprises you can run into that look correct but don't behave correctly--because the code was written under the assumption that it was working with a `class`.  Surprises are bad for people who have to maintain the software.

What that means is the following code can behave very differently depending on whether `Message` is a struct or a class:

```
public static void CreateTitle(Message message)
{
    message.Title = "Created the Title";
}

public static void Main()
{
    Message m = new Message
    {
        Title = "Unset",
        Content = "Message content"
    };

    CreateTitle(m);

    Console.WriteLine($"> {m.Title}: {m.Message}");
}
```

If `Message` is a class you will see:

```
> Created the Title: Message content
```

If `Message` is a struct you will see:

```
> Unset: Message content
```

This is actually desirable when you are using a `struct` to pass progress state through an event.  Essentially your processing code can keep counting and a snapshot of the `struct` is copied to the event handler.

However, if you are dealing with general data management, you will most likely need the semantics of a `class`.  The reasons for the list of caveats from Microsoft is to force you to think about the implications.  In most cases you'll want the behavior of a `class`.

---

Bonus fact, you can make the `CreateTitle()` method behave the same regardless of whether `Message` is a `struct` or a `class` if you explicitly tell it to pass by reference:

```
public static void CreateTitle(ref Message message) { /* .... */ }
```

Disclaimer: This is a contrived example to show the practical implications of the types of surprises to expect when using `struct` instead of `class`.  I don't actually write code this way.

Comment: You say "if you are dealing with general data management, you will most likely need the semantics of a class." but even according to your own explanation the behaviour I am asking for is that of value types.

Comment: If that's the behavior you want, then go for it.  Just keep in mind that you want to avoid mixing objects and structs as much as possible or weird things can happen that are hard to explain (personal experience).  I also wouldn't worry about the 16 byte rule until you actually have a measured performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the difference between a class and a struct is that a struct is a more basic, non-object-oriented feature.

Internally, classes are implemented as a programming pattern built upon structs - the extra behaviour and functionality which classes have can be entirely re-implemented in terms of structs and procedural code.

The distinction is retained (i.e. structs remain in modern languages) mainly for performance reasons on the one hand (classes consume more memory and have overheads in their execution, and are stored by default on the heap instead of the stack), and interop reasons on the other (i.e. to interact with external code that is written and called in a non-object-oriented way - either due to it's age or due to performance reasons in turn).

When I say performance, to be clear in most cases I'm talking about an extra couple of bytes of memory, or a few extra machine instructions per method call - a grave inefficiency 40 years ago, but not often nowadays (except for certain operating system functions or specific algorithms). The same arguments were had over the use of `GOTO` statements (i.e. the argument between structured and unstructured language features).

The underlying difference is also blurred in many general purpose languages.

For example, some object-oriented features, like member methods, can be added to structs without any additional overhead - but those members are not implemented as function pointers stored within the struct, as they are in classes.

It is the storage, and re-writing, of internally-stored function pointers, which permits the member methods of classes to be: (a) overridden without rewriting (or re-implementing) the code of the base class, and (b) called directly from external code, in a way that member methods on structs cannot be.

In most cases nowadays, any use of structs where a class will do, is a premature and unnecessary optimisation.

Answer (score -1):

Classes aren't just about retrieval. They can also be used to enforce contracts and invariants on your data: for example, that their address is valid. If you aren't checking for invariants on your data then go ahead, use a struct. Otherwise, consider using a class instead.

Comment: In OO, you should NOT do that. Address.Validate() is "using OO features", but not "writing OO code". In Germany, an address is a street, a house number, a zip code and a city name. The UK have it similar, but instead of a house number you can have something like "The blue house at the end of the street". In the Netherlands, a zip code and a house number is enough for mail to arrive at the correct place. So now Address has 3 different ValidateCountryX() and one Validate() which decides which one too use. Those functions are related to each other, so you probably want to group them together.

Comment: What is the way to group functionality in C#? Classes.  `class AddressValidator`. Now these things behave like you'd expect them to: An address - like"Baguette street 3, Paris" - doesn't know if it's valid. It doesn't have a GoogleMapsApi and makes an asynchronous call to check whether it is correct. An AddressValidator doing and having those things does make a lot of sense though.  Also, in 100 years: `class MarsAddressValidator` - BAM functionality added without even needing to touch any existing code.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz that's a limited view of OO. Carefully verifying class invariants is central to Bertrand Meyer-style Design by Contract OOP, which is highly effective for writing high-assurance and formally verified object code. Granted, Eiffel and Ada are a little more suited to DbC than C#, but it's certainly untrue that "you should NOT do that".

Comment: Design by contract vs defensive design is orthogonal to OO vs functional. I am not an authority, so I can't really tell anybody what they should and shouldn't do, so let me correct that: "Address.Validate() is not OO code". I mean, if you ask a child "who can I ask if this address is right" and it answers "the address itself", you should get that child to a shrink.

Comment: On the other hand, it's both reasonable and widely accepted to say that the Address carries the _type information_ of being an Address. It's also good practice to place database constraints on your Address table as opposed to making a separate "Address Validation" table. Preserving invariants isn't a crazy thing at all.

Comment: I'm not so sure SQL best practices should guide general purpose programming. I'm also not saying it's crazy - it's done a lot and it works. It's just not "true" OO.