# If there would be no stack, would the 16 byte limit for structs still make sense?

Tags: c#, data-structures

From the official docs:

> AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>       [...]
>       It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
>       [...]

I know that one reason for keeping it under 16 bytes is that structs are intended to be used on the stack. However, are there other reasons?

In order to not accidentally create an XY problem, what I want to know is:
**Does this 16 byte rule still make sense in a situation where I use a struct as a private field in a class?**

We all love code, so here's an example:

```
public struct Address
{
    public readonly string Line1;
    public readonly string Line2;

    public Address(string line1, string line2)
    {
        Line1 = line1;
        Line2 = line2;
    }

}

public class Person
{
    private Address _address;

    [...]

    public void ChangeAddressLine1(string newLine1)
    {
        _address = new Address(newLine1, _address.Line2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we still [trying to use `struct`s as DTO's?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/362824) :P

Comment: Your `Adress` struct actually requires a size of 16 bytes in x64 mode, and 8 bytes in x86 mode, not more. String members are nothing but references to string objects, and references are implemented in the CLI as pointers.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Nah, I'll probably never get to that. Just trying to make sense of why structs are even there or if they have any role in Clean Code.

Comment: @Doc Brown My mistake for not mentioning I'm working in x64. However, take note that the docs say "_under_ 16 bytes" - so according to that a struct can't even handle 2 strings .

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz: huh? You didn't take that 16 bytes **recommendation** (not more!) literally, don't you? This is a soft limit, surely you can make structs bigger than that if you like, it is just a matter of performance and resources, which for 99,9% of all real world programs won't matter. And if a struct need 15, 16 or 24 bytes does not make a big difference for most situations.

Comment: The `struct` keyword has nothing whatsoever to do with the Clean Code book.  Microsoft didn't consult Uncle Bob before  they put the `struct` keyword into the language, and there's nothing about the `struct` keyword that is specific to what Uncle Bob teaches.

Comment: @DocBrown Oh I know it's possible. What I mean is, _according to the guidelines_. Somebody wrote those and put the point "under 16 bytes" in there. There were probably reasons for that. If I know those reasons, I know better when to pragmatically follow the guidelines and when not.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Why do you make me explain that somebody writing code according to Clean Code might use C# and thus has the option of using structs? You have 150k rep here and your profile says you've been a "software developer for many years" - you are well aware of this fact.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz: I don't know why you keep arguing with me about this.  The `struct` keyword has a very specific meaning that you'd know clearly if you took the few minutes to research it.  That meaning has very little to do with what's in the Clean Code book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should prefer small structs because structs will likely be copied, and smaller structs are cheaper to copy.

The [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) do provide a bit more context for that 16-byte size limit:

> Next, reference type assignments copy the reference, whereas value type assignments copy the entire value. Therefore, assignments of large reference types are cheaper than assignments of large value types.

Assuming a word size of 8 bytes, a 16-byte struct is only twice as large as a pointer to a reference type, thus still comparably efficient to copy.

This is completely unrelated to limited stack size. The stack typically has far more space than you might think, unless you're writing deeply recursive algorithms.

In C and C++, it is common to store significant amounts of data on the stack, and these languages only have value types. But unlike C# they can specify whether a struct is passed by value (and thus copied), or by reference or pointer (without a copy). The C++ Core Guidelines [recommend](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#fcall-parameter-passing) that parameters are passed by reference, unless the type is known to be be efficiently copyable (trivially copyable without invoking copy constructors, and only up to two or three words large). Under those circumstances, a copy is more efficient than passing by reference because the copy avoids pointer indirection.

Comment: Can you make it a little clearer why you went into such great detail about C++ in the last paragraph, and how that relates to C# specifically?

Comment: @RobertHarvey When a value type should be copied does not depend very much on the language. So looking at the conventions of a language where copies of value types are far more common than in C# is useful. In particular, the C++ conventions are well-documented and in this case provide a transferable insight.

Comment: C# can pass structs by both value and reference. For example, passing by reference is mandatory for the SpinWait structure.

Comment: @IamIC You're right! Especially with C# 7 ref locals, unnecessary struct copies can be avoided. But this requires users to know whether a type is a struct or a class. One recommendation is to make all structs immutable. Because immutability makes copies un-observable, it doesn't matter whether a type is implemented as a struct or a class. Once a struct grows it can be replaced by an equivalent reference type.

Comment: I chose this answer because it mentions - in a pragmatic way - why limiting the size would still make sense in the given situation.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that one reason for keeping it under 16 bytes is that structs are intended to be used on the stack.

The manner in which structs are stored in C# *is an implementation detail.*  They might be stored on the stack, but they might not.

> Does this 16 byte rule still make sense in a situation where I use a struct as a private field in a class?

What matters is whether you want *value* or *reference* semantics, not the absolute size of the struct.  If you're willing to put up with the copying, your structs can be as large as you want.  In most cases, however, you're going to be better served by using classes for larger data types.

**Further Reading**
[The Truth About Value Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this is the second time where I have a question with "struct" in the title where you answer the question "When should I use a struct". I wanted to understand the 16 byte rule from the docs. You _do_ mention in one sub clause that it doesn't matter without any explanation -  but that seems more like an accidental byproduct of answering your favorite question.

Comment: Actually, if you read my answer carefully, I think you'll find that I'm merely debunking some of your incorrect assumptions.  The 16 byte rule is there to discourage folks like you from using value semantics for everything.

Comment: You didn't debunk any of those quotes, you _barely_ touch their subjects. I guess "folks like me" are people who don't know as much about structs yet? Well, I'm trying to learn more about them. _That's why I'm asking these questions._ It's not only me though - do you think anybody seeking answer to these questions and landing here is going to be satisfied with the answer "It doesn't matter, [When to use a struct]"?

Comment: I don't know why you're being so hostile, @Raphael.  Part of understanding is starting with the right assumptions, and since the fundamental assumption in your question that "structs are intended to be used on the stack" is patently incorrect, doesn't that sort of invalidate part or all of your question?  Part of the learning process is admitting when your wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to find the hostility in my comment. I even took you and me out of the equation as to not hurt any feelings: If ANYBODY searches this question and reads an answer by ANYBODY that says "It doesn't matter, [When to use a struct]", that answer is just not helping them in their learning effort.

Comment: Well, I don't mean to be hostile, just as you probably are not meaning to be nitpicky. Yes, I am wrong because structs are not literally intended to be used on the stack, per the design document. But does that information help here? In theory, the theory is always right, but when I click "compile", I end up with structs on the stack and have to work with that.

Comment: If you're working in C#, *you shouldn't ever have to think about the stack.*  From a programmer point of view, the stack essentially does not exist in C#.  Like I said before, it sounds like you come from a C background.  A lot of what we've covered here has relevance in C; in fact, structs in C are used exactly in the manner described in your first question.  `struct`s work differently in C#.  That's not being nitpicky; knowing how the keywords work in your programming language of choice is kinda fundamental to being effective in the language.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you access/use the struct that is the private member of the object.

In an access of the struct member from the object, immediately followed by a struct member access, the IL will directly follow these steps making it appear to obtain the struct and then from that the member of the struct.

However, the JIT will interpret this as addressing calculations ultimately intended to access just the member of the struct.  Despite the IL instruction to do so, it will not load/copy the whole struct (e.g. to the stack) in order to access one field of the struct.  Thus, the JIT should generally produce the same code to access `person._address.Line1` as for `person.Line1`, e.g. as if the `Line1`/`Line2` fields were directly in the `Person` object.

However, if you access the struct as a whole without immediately accessing a struct member, it will probably make a copy to work with; sometimes that is strictly necessary but other times might have been avoided.

Handling of structs (such as optimizing copying in JIT'ed code) is an area of ongoing improvement in the .NET JIT.